# Could not create the Java Virtual Machine In MacOS

Tags: java, tomcat

I have Tomcat 8.0.53 and Java 8 for the developing a normal Spring application but when I am running the server actually I get this type of error

> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
> -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/lalatendu/Software/apache-tomcat-8.0.52/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
> in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.

Can you please tell me what to do for this?

System configuration -

1. OS: MacOS
2. RAM: 8GB

Comment: which java version you are using?

Comment: I am using java8

Comment: The latest released tomcat is 8.0.52, how come you're using 8.0.53? BTW: The error suggests you are using Java 9, not Java 8.

Comment: Thank's correct I am using tomcat 8.0.52 ,that is typo mistake

Comment: but I am using java 8 not java 9

Comment: I got note from this page: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html,  `endorsed directory is not created by default, endorsed feature is no longer supported with Java 9, ` you need to set variable JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS in system properties

Comment: Thanks for the information .Can you just brief me about this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Apache Tomcat 9.x for Java 8. See the supported version for Java 8.

https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: Tomcat 8 also supports Java 8.

Comment: Thanks  but actually I am using eclipse mars where we don't have support for tomcat 9 , Is there any other way or we have to download other eclipse for this.

Comment: You can use Eclipse Oxygen

Comment: That's work for me but I have to download eclipse and tomcat again, Anyway thank you so much

Comment: It's my pleasure to help